# How to temporarily disable log4js logging in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging

There are a few third party libraries that are using log4js to output their logs. I know it sounds counter-intuitive but I would like to disable these logs temporarily to be able to investigate an issue that I have.

How do I temporarily disable log4js logs temporarily in code in javascript? Specifically nodejs.

Comment: [`By default, log4js will not output any logs (so that it can safely be used in libraries).`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js). Do you have any code that configures log4js in your own project?

Comment: @A1rPun Hey, nope. No code that changes the configuration. And messages are only being displayed for that specific third party library (Hyperledger Fabric Node JS SDK)

Answer (score 1):

In log4js 5.3.0 (not sure how many versions back it's the same) you can do this by turning everything off temporarily at the root logger, which affects every other logger:

```
log4js.getLogger().level = 'off';
```

A full example:

```
#!/bin/env node

const log4js = require('log4js');

log4js.configure({
    appenders: {
        out: { type: "stdout" }
    },
    categories: {
        default: {
            appenders: [ "out" ],
            level: "info"
        }
    }
});

const rootLogger = log4js.getLogger();

const log = log4js.getLogger('foo');

log.info('this is on - turning off');

rootLogger.level = 'off';

log.info('this is off - turning back on');

rootLogger.level = 'info';

log.info('this is back on');
```

Which gives you:

```
[2019-11-13T22:00:37.541] [INFO] foo - this is on - turning off
[2019-11-13T22:00:37.544] [INFO] foo - this is back on
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `app.js` file of my nodejs application I place the following code to temporarily disable log4js logs from thirdparty libraries.

```
const log4js = require('log4js')
log4js.configure({})
```

This works for disabling the logs.

Comment: Just for info, I think that must have worked with an earlier version of log4js, but it seems to demand a proper configuration now so {} throws an error.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:31
      throw new Error(`Problem with log4js configuration: (${util.inspect(config, { depth: 5 })})`
      ^
Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({}) - must have a property "appenders" of type object.